# Flurry AppSpot Test Ads Not Appearing on Device

Tags: ios, flurry

I have integrated Flurry AppSpot into my iOS App as per their instructions. This all seems to work fine when I test this on the simulator, all the correct delegate lifecycle methods are called and some test Ads appear in the top banner. However, when I try to run this on a real device (I've tried a few different types) all the correct calls are made and the delegate methods are called, but the Ad doesn't appear. I'm guessing there shouldn't be any distinction between these two modes but can't seem to find any information to confirm this.

Has anyone else tried integrating AppSpot ads and either experienced the same issue or had this working successfully on real devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed the delegate code and all started working again. Added the delegate code back in and it continued to work.